# How do I hide Google Ad Manager ads on mobile devices?

Tags: google-ad-manager

I have a `<div class="ad-container">` that contains my Google Ad Manager snippet for displaying ad banners, and my CSS has media queries to hide it on smaller devices:

```
.ad-container {
    display: none;
}
```

Will that prevent the ad from triggering impressions in Google Ad Manager? Or will the impression be counted (but obviously never get clicked since the user can't see it)?

Otherwise how do I do this correctly to not trigger an impression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidding a placement container won't prevent adserver calls. Most of the time, Google Ad Manager will try to force the display of the ad to prevent unviewable ads.

In your case, I would use the sizeMapping (see [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/ad-sizes#responsive_ads)) to define sizes attached to the banner placement.
Here is a sample :

```
var adSlot = googletag
.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [728, 90], 'banner')
.addService(googletag.pubads());

var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping()
  .addSize([640, 480], [728, 90]) //allow 728x90 ad banner for screens bigger than 639x479px
  .addSize([0, 0], []) //below 639x479px window size, no ad size attached / allowed
  .build();

adSlot.defineSizeMapping(mapping);
```

Using responsive sizeMapping is the correct way to dispatch size per window size.

Comment: In my case, this code works on mobile devices, but not when resizing a desktop browser window. For example, the ad will be hidden when a narrow window is opened. When a window is made wider, the ad appears. When the window is made smaller again, the ad does not disappear. Any idea how to hide the ad when resizing the window?

Comment: @apiljic : in your case, your need to watch for the window.resize event and refresh the ad call once the new screen size has been established. When refreshed, the ad server will detect the new screen size and call the right ad banner size.

Comment: I understood this is what Google code should be doing (and it does in all cases except this one scenario). In any case, I fixed the issue, I just was expecting it would work on its own.